# How to derive value of VM generation in azure via python sdk

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I would like to find VM generation value of a given VM in azure ..

What I looked at is to explore Disk profile
`os_disk_name = virtual_machine.storage_profile.os_disk.name os_disk = compute_client.disks.get(GROUP_NAME, os_disk_name)`

But I don't find generation info..which profile will have this VM generation information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debug, please use the code below:

```
myvm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(myvm_resource_group,VM_NAME, expand='instanceView')

print("vm generation: " + myvm.instance_view.hyper_vgeneration)
```